# Convert String to Image in Android?

Tags: android, string, bitmap, imageview

So, here is the thing. I am receiving an imagepath through WebService. I am storing the imagepath in a String. Now I want to convert the String to Bitmap and display the image in an imageView. I tried many codes from the examples in the internet but are not working.

Try 1:

```
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagelogo);
      imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
      imageView2.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

Try 2: First I am converting String to string Base64 and then string Base64 to Bitmap.

```
     byte[] data;
     String base64;
      {
       try {
          data = imagelogo.getBytes("UTF-8");
          String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT);
          Log.i("Base 64 ", base64);
          } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      public Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
       try {
          byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(base64 ,Base64.DEFAULT);
          Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
          return bitmap;
       } catch(Exception e) {
          e.getMessage();
          return null;
       }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have a url to the image and you want to show it in `ImageView` then just use Picasso library http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: Okay. Thank you, M-WaJeEh. That's a simple and good idea.

Comment: Why do you use ```imagelogo.getBytes("UTF-8");```? Your string is probably not UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Refer to Android Doc (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)

Comment: what is the error or exception you getting ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Oh God, you can't convert a String of image path into a Bitmap! The image path isn't the image itself!
**You need to download the image from internet through the image path and store it into a local file**. The you need to call this:

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(localImagePath);
```

to load the Image.

Comment: You don't **need** to store it in a file.

Comment: @weston yes, indeed. I just try to tell the poster the difference between the image path linked to the the server and one linked to the local storage system.

Comment: Yeah I get that, but remember they will take what you write literally. And they will look up how to download and store in a file and then where to put that file in android and they will add file system permissions and they simply don't need to go down that route.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-loading-image-from-url-http/:

> ```
> int loader = R.drawable.loader;
>      
>     // Imageview to show
>     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
>      
>     // Image url
>     String image_url = "http://api.androidhive.info/images/sample.jpg";
>      
>     // ImageLoader class instance
>     ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
>      
>     // whenever you want to load an image from url
>     // call DisplayImage function
>     // url - image url to load
>     // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
>     // image - ImageView
>     imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, loader, image);
> ```