# Get images from PHP-MySql server to Android using json

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-bitmap

i am devloping an application which download image from php-server and display image in image view ..but when i receive image from php page

```
if (!empty($result)) {
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        $user = array();
        $user["image"] = base64_encode($result["image"]);
        $response["success"] = 1;
       $response["image_table"] = array();

        array_push($response["image_table"], $user);
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No Image found";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

it gives me json response like this

```
03-30 04:43:44.013: D/Image:(2770): {"success":1,"image_table":   [{"image":"\/9j\/4VeRRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAMAAABBAABAAAA..........
03-30 04:43:44.253: D/skia(2770): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

i m decoding this image string to bitmap like this....

```
json= jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_img_address, "GET", params);

        Log.d("Image: ", json.toString());

        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                address = json.getJSONArray(TAG_IMAGE_TABLE);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = address.getJSONObject(i);
                    image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                     byte[] dwimage = Base64.decode(image.getBytes());
                      System.out.println(dwimage);
                      bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(dwimage, 0, dwimage.length);
                } 
            } else {

            }
        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and i m using this bm to onotherclass which set bmp to imageview

```
   ivProperty.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

but it dosent display anything......my asynck task activity is not finished and it continuesly running...
my question is that how to display bmp to imageview and why my asyncktask is not finished........thx in advance....

Comment: friends i need your help.......help me

Comment: Use this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29341566/4693713

Comment: byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

Comment: Hey @signare that is not working....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use binary decoding using base64 decode, and you will get image as bitmap..

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

Comment: Hey Zinal Do you use Base64 Util Class or own developed class